# Invalid literal for int() with base 10: Python

Tags: python, python-3.3

I am trying to write a simple beginner program that acts as a tip calculator. Problem is, whenever I try to run the code, and input a decimal such as 25.2 for the cost of the meal, or "a", which is the value ive assigned to bind to the input, I get an error, and I cannot figure out why. Here is the code. Go easy on me, I'm new at this.

```
print("How much is your bill?")
a = int(input())
print("And the sales tax in your state?")
b = int(input())
print("How much do you wish to tip? (in percent)")
c = int(input())
d = b / 100
e = d * a
f = e + a
g = c / 100
h = g * f
i = h + f
print(i)
```

And here is my error message.

```
How much is your bill?
10.5
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python33\Tip Calculator.py", line 3, in <module>
a = int(input())
```

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include the *full* stack trace... so it includes the actual trace back message...

Answer (score 2):

It's because `10.5` is not an int. Instead use:

```
a = float(input())
```

or preferably [Decimal](http://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html) as you're dealing with monetary amounts you want to have fixed precision

```
from decimal import *

a = Decimal(input())​
```

Answer (score 1):

If you expect the user to input a `float`, casting to an `int` will error.

Try casting to a float. Something like this

```
a = float(input())
```

`Decimal` is another option.

Comment: Converting the float to an int will drop the decimal component of the number.